# Being directed to hacked site only when searched through Yahoo

Tags: system-compromise, yahoo

A local wolf sanctuary had just posted a warning on Facebook to not visit their site because it had been hacked. However, it only sends you to the hacked site when searching through Yahoo.

I was curious as to how this might be working and why it's different?

The site is `whar.org` (assuming it hasn't been fixed at the time of reading).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just verified this.

If the request header contains the Referer (which your browser adds after being refered by another site), you are redirected to the fake page.

[image: Request containing referer]

This is the response, which causes the "redirect":
[image: Response received when HTTP contains referer]

Now we modify the request to not contain the REFERER: header:
[image: Request without referer]

And the correct website is loading.
[image: Response without referer]

So basically, the "hacker" checks the REFERER header, and if it is set to Yahoo (or possibly others), it will show you the wrong page.

Comment: To be a bit pedantic, yahoo doesn't add the referer header, your browser does. Also, please copy text rather than adding pictures.

Comment: You're correct, edited the answer. Apologies for the images.